# Java: Referencing fields in a child from the parent class

Tags: java, polymorphism

so I'm working an an assignment for my Java class and I can't figure out a way to reference fields in a child from my parent class without having to pass them in through the constructor.

For example I want my parent class to have this method:

```
@Override
    public String getImageFileName() {     
        String result = IMG_DEAD;
        if (isAlive()) {
            result = IMG_ALIVE;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I want the Strings of IMG_DEAD and IMG_ALIVE to be defined in my child since every child will have different ones.

What is the best way to do this? I've tried using static fields but I always end up just referencing the ones in my parent.

I got it to work just passing the values through the constructor but I'd rather not have to do that if there is a better way. These variables also should be able to be static since they are constant for each class.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like each child needs to provide specifics on that. The best way to do this is usually a method in the parent that the child overrides, something like this:

```
protected String imageFileName(boolean alive) {
    return alive ? DEFAULT_IMG_ALIVE : DEFAULT_IMG_DEAD;
}
```

Then, in your child classes, override that method:

```
@Override
protected String imageFileName(boolean alive) {
    return alive ? GRUE_IMG_ALIVE : GRUE_IMG_DEAD;
}
```

If you want to *require* images from the children, without a default, make the parent method `abstract` instead.

Comment: The problem with that is my children would all be overriding this method with the exact same method which to me seems like it defeats the purpose of inheriting the method. Along with that, if I ever wanted to change that method I would have to change it in all of the children. I wish there was a way to override the fields in children but not having to override methods.

Comment: @RobertCordingly Overriding "with the exact same method" is *the entire point* of polymorphism--you provide substitute behavior for each class where desired. Overriding fields would be a serious headache, and you'd still have the exact same hypothetical future maintenance problem.